# How to handle headless chrome network activity?

Tags: headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I can run

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot http://google.com
```

But besides screenshot I also need a list of requested urls (scripts, images, etc) and their responses with response statuses.

Is it possible to handle network activity?

Comment: You should use combination of "chrome-remote-interface" and "chrome-launcher" NPM libraries